# when I use multiple values in my filter some data goes missing in cognos

Tags: cognos

Hi I have very little experience with cognos. Currently I'm running a report that shows even time a change was made to a job by its job number. I have a multi line text box prompt set up. When I put just one job number I get all the data I'm looking for. But when I use large number of job numbers. I get all the job numbers to show up on my report however some of the changes are missing. Please help

Comment: What "Changes"?  Are you querying from a database which you are updating on the fly?  It sounds like you could be seeing caching behaviour - in your Query in Report Studio, what do you have defined for caching?

Comment: What does your filter look like?